# Airflow server missing git

Tags: airflow

I have a puckel airflow server installation with celery executor everything has been great but today i realized the docker image doesnt have git.

Im wondering if anyknow knows how this docker comes without git and without a way to install these packages since the user running commands in the docker is airflow with limited privileges cannot run apt-get... unless i explicity do docker run -u root but this isnt ideal for me.

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

Comment: According to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile#L39) the image should have git. An option would be to just grab the Dockerfile and add anything that is needed to it?

Comment: root@db1700f15476:/usr/local/airflow# git
bash: git: command not found

and when i try to install it from Docker file i get  permission denied

List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied

Comment: You could also try to open a GitHub issue for that repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i need to use the USER root in the docker file to install this :)

Answer (score 0):

FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
USER root
RUN apt update
RUN apt install git -y

Comment: Please provide a description to your code and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your image from puckel/docker-airflow, creating a file called `Dockerfile` with the following code:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
RUN apt update && apt install git -y
```

After it run, in the same directory:

```
$ docker build -t docker-airflow-git:latest .
```

Now you have the `docker-airflow-git` image to run or push to a repository