# How can we perform git push using airflow dag?

Tags: git, airflow

How can we perform git push using airflow dag?
I am trying to perform git push for a specific branch via an airflow dag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BashOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html) to perform any bash command (including `git`).

Apart from the link I already included, you can do something like this:

```py
git_push_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='git_push_example',
    # "scripts" folder is under "/usr/local/airflow/dags"
    bash_command="scripts/git_push.sh",
    dag=dag
)
```

And inside `scripts/git_push.sh` something like:

```
cd folder/you/want/
git push
```

Remember to give it execution permissions with:

```
chmod +x scripts/git_push.sh
```

You can also check [this post](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-bashoperator/#Executing_bash_scripts_with_the_BashOperator) with very useful information.

Comment: That's how it should be done in theory. But the question is, will the airflow worker have git installed in it, to be able to run the git command?

Comment: No, you need to install that. If you're using `docker` you can install that as part of your `Dockerfile`. How to install that depends a lot on your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar question.

The approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68001043/3811763 is the right approach. But it will only be successful if your airflow environment, specifically your airflow workers, has git installed in them.

If you are running your own cluster, setting up git in your airflow worker won't be challenging. For example, as done here - [Airflow server missing git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261952/airflow-server-missing-git)

In my case, I am using AWS MWAA, and they don't support installing packages on demand or per use-case in the airflow environment. So far I could not get any solution for this.

References for the above claims:
https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/issues/36
https://repost.aws/questions/QUnSS0qL7PSsieu7biYQDK5Q/mwaa-environment-issue-with-git